# Javascript event object: Where is the selector

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have following setup in my Backbone View:

```
var SomeView;

SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() { this.render(); },
    render: function() { // render form },
    events: {
        "keydown form.registration input": "checkInput"
    },
    checkInput: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        // this doesn't work but I am searching for such a function
        var attr = e.getAttributeWhichTriggeredEvent;
        $(attr).val();
        // validate...
    } 
});
```

As you see, I would like to get the selector of the element which triggered the event, so that I can, for example, use the input value.

As I looked through the console in Chromium, I found some (current) target attributes in the event object. Unfortunatly they don't contain anything which I could use to identicate the element but maybe I just not looked enough..

So how do I do this?

Comment: Why do you think "they don't contain anything which I could use to identicate the element"?

Comment: My fault, I thought that HTMLInputElement was a just a type saying what sort of element we have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want..

```
$(e.target).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM Event objects have a [type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#event-types-list) that reflects the type of event that dispatched them (e.g. click, mousedown, etc.). They also have [properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#interface-Event) for *target* and *currentTarget* that reference DOM elements related to the event, one of those may suit.

Note that older IE doesn't support *event.target* but has *event.srcElement* instead.